# what are settings to be done to host SharePoint site on internet?

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, public-website, web-application-zones, internet-sites

I am trying to host SharePoint 2013 site on internet using an exposed IP and mapping it as a host URL to internet zone. Tried using AAM also but not achieving it.
Let me know if anyone has confirmed steps to make public facing SharePoint site.

Thanks!

Comment: what issue you are getting? what AAM settings are? anyfirewall?

Comment: yes firewall there. i am not able to browse my serverurl using ip address. firewall settings has been done.

Comment: can you help me with it,any idea?

Comment: check this one http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a6d3f3a-d6fb-4dc7-bde2-ec3ecc8e03e4/configure-sharepoint-2010-on-the-internet

Answer (score 0):

Creating a host entry resolved my machine name and through firewall managed mappings for IP to the exposed IP and was able to make my SharePoint site internet facing.

Thanks!